# Quickly copy and paste buttons in Flash CS5

Tags: flash

I'm extremely new to Flash, and I'm using CS5.

I have a button with animations on scroll-over. How can I 'duplicate' this button, as I want several more buttons with the same template, just different text (and different functions called)?

Sorry for the foolish question, but the Duplicate button is frustrating, as when I change the text in the new button it changes the text in the other button. It's like I'm changing a template.

Perhaps it is a misunderstanding of symbols? I believe symbols are basically template classes...is there a way to generate a new instance of a button symbol?

EDIT: SOLUTION/WORKAROUND

I've found a workaround.

Simply make your first button, then in the Library duplicate it. Edit the new button from the library panel, then you can click and drag the new button onto the stage.

-Would've made a real answer, but this account doesn't have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the item you want to copy, select copy then paste. each button is a new instance but with the same values for example if you were to edit one of the symbols/buttons it will effect the others aswell.

There is also another option to duplicate which will allow you now to edit that buttons/Symbols contents with out effecting the other symbols properties.

Note: if you have two buttons with the same instance name, the last button/Symbol created will only effect the action assigned to it.make sure you give them different instance names if your planning on using it for actionScript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're just updating the text in the button, consider making the TextField dynamic and giving in an instance name like `txt`. Then use ActionScript to change the text for different buttons. For example, something like this would work for three buttons with the instances names `btn1` - `btn3`.

```
btn1.txt.text = "Button 1";
btn2.txt.text = "Button 2";
btn3.txt.text = "Button 3";
```

This way when you decide that you want to change the appearance of all the buttons later on, you don't have to tear your hair out over needing to update the 40 copies you made before.